# What is the unit of Width() and Height() APIs of a Qt widget?

Tags: qt, widget, width, pixel, points

What is the unit of Width() and Height() APIs of a Qt widget? Qt documentation says int -
Is it points or pixels? Suppose I have developed some Qt Dialog with many child widgets, is it necessary to scale the widgets based on the screen DPI? or Qt takes care of it automatically?

I know that pixels to points conversion is needed for font sizes. Is it also needed for widgets heights and widths and all other properties like padding, etc?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs, the short answer is:

> Now, geometry is specified in device independent pixels. This includes
> widget and item geometry, event geometry, desktop, window and screen
> geometry, as well as animation velocities. The output is rendered in
> device pixels, which corresponds to the display resolution. The
> devicePixelRatio is the ratio between the device independent pixels
> and the device pixel coordinate system.

High DPI support is a tricky subject. Please see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html) for an explanation of how Qt handles high DPI support on various windowing systems.

And, as always, it is best to use layouts in lieu of hardcoding widget geometry.